# how to upload video using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

In phonegap using javascript or jquery  how  to send video as bytearray  to server using Ajax with wcf rest service (or) from javascript to asp.net

please guide me.

thanks in advance

Comment: ...What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have updated my post,please see that and guide me

Comment: Well done, but StackOverflow is where you can get help with existing code that does not work. Not where you can get someone to write your code for you. Try it yourself first, come back when you encounter a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well have you looked at [FileTransfer.upload](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_upload)? It uses a HTTP POST and not Ajax but it gets the job done.